# Performance of string buffer as function of number of appends

Tags: performance, string-concatenation

I recently heard that there is an optimal point, where using a string buffer no longer offers better performance than simple concatenation. Apparently this was measured in the number of elements being appended (somewhere around 6).

Is this true?

Comment: Is this relevant to a certain language and/or runtime?  For example, allocating memory on the heap is [typically] much faster in .NET than it is with C++.

Comment: Dynamic languages may pre-allocate growth space to a scalar character string and thus making an append operation low cost.

Comment: I don't know if that's true or not, but a pretty decent rule of thumb to go by is that if you're repeatedly appending to a string in a loop, use a string buffer, but if you're just doing a reasonable series of appends (so not, for whatever reason, doing a hundred or a thousand appends outside of a loop), go with simple concatenation. Any performance difference should be negligible, and I would think most modern compilers/possibly interpreters would be able to optimize the concatenations for you in that case anyway (as the amount of space needed is available at compile-time/runtime).